# Selenium RC and IE Script Error - Remote procedure call failed

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-rc

My Test setup consists of several Java test cases running in IE6 using Selenium RC and TestNG.

During my test runs, the following IE Script error popup comes randomly. Upon trying to dismiss this popup by clicking Yes, the test run hangs and I have to kill the entire run.

I have tried disabling popup blocker and the MDM service but without luck.

Any pointers to what causes these errors and how to go about avoiding them??

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

I have just had the same problem. And this post helped: http://manfredlange.blogspot.com/2009/11/ie8-and-selenium-rc-tests-wont-execute.html

So run selenium with admin rights and then you will not get this error. If you use visual studio (maybe also the same with eclipse or other java IDE) run it as administrator and run the tests like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running my selenium tests from the command line, and I found that running the command shell "as administrator" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and unchecking the "work offline" of ie fixed it.